# How to upload multiple files to sourceforge.net?

Tags: php, web-development

I recently added the details of my php mvc framework to Sourceforge which can be found here:

https://sourceforge.net/projects/ezphp/

I also added repository:

https://ezphp.svn.sourceforge.net/svnroot/ezphp/

using TotoiseSVN.

Now i want to upload the files of my framework, but there is the option of uploading only single file at Sourceforge which is a headache. How do i upload multiple files or can i use TotoiseSVN for that if yes then how?

Basically the reason why i am uploading my framework there is that other developers from around the globe could participate in the further development of the project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use the svn import command or the import option in tortise (i assume there is one).

```
svn import -m "Initial import of framework files" /path/to/local/files https://ezphp.svn.sourceforge.net/svnroot/ezphp/
```

Comment: @prodigitalson: thanks i hope that helps, thanks +1

Answer (score 1):

Like said before, use an SVN client, I suggest [Tortoise SVN](http://tortoisesvn.net/downloads)